# Lua making ball spin like a real ball roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

how can we make a ball when ever you step on it it rotates in the direction like when you step on ball on real life i serched it on internet but i cant find any result please If anyone have a solution please reply me

Comment: you searched it, but can you provide how those results didn't help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question right, but simple spherical parts act like that due to the physics engine. It might not be obvious how they rotate, because of the default material. So try the following: Create an empty game and put the following as a script into your workspace and do nothing else:

```
local ball = Instance.new("Part", workspace)
ball.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
```

When you now start the game, you'll stand exactly on top of the ball and when walking forward, the ball will turn into the direction as you would expect. Now you can chase it and jump on it, etc.

Comment: I want it to work like a real ball e.g if i stand on hte corner it should spin and i should fall

Comment: So you mean not falling on your feet but falling on the ground, like tripping? you could do that by turning on the player's humanoid's "Physics" state. But only when you determine that he/she should be tripping, since while that state is turned on you have no control over the player.

Comment: what happens if you stand on a ball as soon as you step into a corner you lose balance now how to that is roblox

Comment: i want it to work like a real ball to spin as you go near edges